# stat_density2d tile geom showing grid when exporting as PDF

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having an issue when exporting `stat_density2d` plots.

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, y = waiting, alpha = ..density..)) +
  stat_density2d(geom = 'tile', contour = F)
```

When exporting as a png it looks like so:

[image]

But when I export as a PDF a grid appears:

[image]

I'm assuming that this is because the boundaries of the tiles overlap and so have equivalent of a doubled alpha value.

How can I edit just the edges of the tiles to stop this from happening?

Secondary question:

As Tjebo mentioned `geom = 'raster'` would fix this problem. However, this raises a new issue that only one group gets plot.

```
df <- faithful
df$new <- as.factor(ifelse(df$eruptions>3.5, 1, 0))

ggplot(df, aes(eruptions, waiting, fill = new, alpha = ..density..)) +
  stat_density2d(geom = 'tile', contour = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = 'blue', '0' = 'red'))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(eruptions, waiting, fill = new, alpha = ..density..)) +
  stat_density2d(geom = 'raster', contour = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = 'blue', '0' = 'red'))
```

[image]

help on this second issue would also be much appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, dependent on an environment ? Here is my code :`g <- ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, y = waiting, alpha = ..density..)) +
  stat_density2d(geom = 'tile', contour = F); pdf("test.pdf"); print(g); dev.off()`

Comment: @cuttlefish44 I still get the same problem with your code. Do you use Rstudio? could that be the issue?

Comment: I could reproduce your issue, but in my case, it goes away depending on the pdf reader I use to open the pdf file. Try other pdf readers or Photoshop/Gimp.

Comment: @Arienrhod Interesting, the issue doesn't arise when using other readers. I wonder what it is about adobe that's causing it.

Comment: I'm really not sure, but it drove me crazy at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I decided to transform my comment into an answer instead. Hopefully it solves your problem.

There is [an old, related google thread on this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/7jzjlN8bupU) - It seems related to how the plots are vectorized in each pdf viewer.

A hack is suggested in this thread, but one solution might simply be to use `geom = 'raster'` instead.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, y = waiting, alpha = ..density..)) +
  stat_density2d(geom = 'raster', contour = F)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you have a look [at the geom_raster documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html) - geom_raster is recommended if you want to export to pdf!

> The most common use for rectangles is to draw a surface. You always want to use geom_raster here because it's so much faster, and produces smaller output when saving to PDF

**edit - second part of the question**

Your tile plot can't be correct - you are creating cut-offs (your x value), so the fill should not overlap. This points to the core of the problem - the `alpha=..density..` probably calculates the density based on the entire sample, and not by group. I think the only way to go is to pre-calculate the density (e.g., using `density()`. In your example, for demonstration purpose, we have this luckily precalculated, as `faithfuld` (this is likely not showing the results which you really want, as it is the density on the entire sample!!).

I'd furthermore recommend not to use numbers as your factor values - this is pretty confusing for you and R. Use characters instead. Also, ideally don't use `df` for a sample data frame, as this is a base R function;)
Hope this helps

```r
mydf <- faithfuld ## that is crucial!!! faithfuld contains a precalculated density column which is needed for the plot!!
mydf$new <- as.factor(ifelse(mydf$eruptions>3.5, 'large', 'small'))

ggplot(mydf, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = new, alpha = density), interpolate = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I've played around with `geom = 'raster'` unfortunately, the graph that I am actually trying to produce has the points filled with a colour in relation to one of two groups. When I try raster only one of the groups shows up.

Comment: @tom91 that sounds solvable - could you try to reproduce this on the eruption sample data and update your question? Or ask another question

Comment: Thanks! so I need to calculate the densities first. Doesn't `density()` only calculate the density of a single variable though? rather than 2d density?

Comment: @tom91 that's a very good question. density was a quick suggestion, not very much thought about it. [Two-Dimensional Kernel Density Estimation would be one way](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/kde2d.html)